# Dark Thumbnails on EC2 with ImageMagick / RMagick

Tags: amazon-ec2, imagemagick, rmagick

With the `yum` installed version of **ImageMagick** on the default Amazon EC2 instance I was getting dark thumbnails via **rmagick**.

How do I get a newer version of **ImageMagick** on **EC2**?

Comment: Answered my own question because I couldn't find this on SO after tracking down an answer.  If someone has a better method, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of the **ImageMagick** [source installation instructions](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix) and some instructions from [a blog](http://openstripe.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-install-latest-imagemagick-on.html), I got the following to work:

**Get rid of the old version**

```
yum remove ImageMagick
```

**Install the dependencies**
You will need the appropriate ImageMagick dependencies for whatever graphic types you expect to convert.

```
yum install wget tcl-devel libpng-devel libjpeg-devel ghostscript-devel bzip2-devel freetype-devel libtiff-devel
```

**`curl` and extract the ImageMagick source**

```
cd ~/
curl -O http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar zxvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
```

**Test configuration**

```
cd ImageMagick-xxx
./configure
```

**Confirm configuration**
There should be a **yes** next to all the image types you anticipate needing to convert, if not see the dependencies step above.

**Build and install**

```
make
make install
```

[image: Thumbnail examples]